# Dynamically generate Google Chart type from Dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts on my web application and would like to change the chart displayed using a dropdown list.

The dropdown list stores the chart type in code behind and I'm trying to insert the VB.net variable in the var chart variable.

var chart = new google.visualization.**datachart**(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
chart.draw(data, options);

The value in bold defines which chart gets displayed (ColumnChart, LineChart etc)

How's best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to set the chart according to the one you want to draw:

```
var chart;
if(chartType== 'LineChart' ){
    chart= new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
}else if(chartType== 'BarChart' ){
    chart= new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
}// and so on

chart.draw(data, options);
```

For a more dynamic way, you would need to use a chartWrapper, which you can set the chart type with a string, or do:

```
chartWrapper.setChartType('LineChart');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this a number of different ways.  juvian pointed out a couple of them, but if you want something more direct from ASP.net:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.<%=chartType %>(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Where `chartType` is a string that matches a chart type, like `"BarChart"` or `"LineChart"`.

If you go this route, you should validate the chart type on the server-side so you don't end up trying to access a chart type that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion asgallant, this is what I tried originally and found problems with. When you try and insert a server side variable into the command you get an error that it expects an identifier and can't accept a server side variable.

Comment: Is it ASP.net that is throwing that error, or javascript?  JS should not be aware of (or care) what the server did on the back-end to adjust your code.